# Return value of first argument of condition without recalculation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I know I can solve it by using a separate cell and make it invisible but I'd like a clean solution for this and use only 1 cell and 1 formula.

For this example I need to get a random number between `X.00` and `Y.00` (with decimals), not lower than `0.00` and not superior than `9.00`. But for this example I am using only 1 condition for avoiding values less than `0.00` to simplify.

I will use `RANDBETWEEN()`. The `X` and `Y` are supplied by 2 other cells on the dummy file bellow: `B3` and `D3`.

The reason why sometimes the random number can be less than `0.00` or above `9.00` is that I need the random result to be between random +/- 1 than `(X+Y)/2`.

Also `X` and `Y` values will vary. Sometimes `X` will be `3.54`, sometimes `8.99` and same for `Y`. For situations when it happens that `X` and `Y` are a low number like `0.5` the `RANDBETWEEN()` function might output a negative number. When so I need the output to be `0.00`. Same for high values. If both `X` and `Y` will be close to `9.00` the result might be something like `9.35`. In this cases I´d need the output to be `9.000`. But in the below formula I am only using cases below zero to make it simple.

So the problem I am unable to resolve is that I need to get the value of the fist argument of the `ÌF()` condition without recalculating it. If I refer to the 3rd argument for `FALSE` then I will recalculate. my formula is this:

```
=IF(
    (RANDBETWEEN(
        ((((B3*100)+(D3*100))/2)-100),
        ((((B3*100)+(D3*100))/2)+100))
        /100)<0,0,
    (RANDBETWEEN(
        ((((B3*100)+(D3*100))/2)-100),
        ((((B3*100)+(D3*100))/2)+100))
        /100))
```

So this will check if the first argument is less than `0.00`, if it is it displays `0.00` if not it recalculates again and this is a problem because it might sometimes recalculate a value less than `0.00`.

[image]

My question is: Is there a way to return the value of the first argument of the condition without recalculation of `RANDBETWEEN()` and without using a separate cell?

If not possible I would also welcome any solution using custom GAS functions.

My dummy file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15YtgUVqDTuC-raMNJiN-YG4j3URaorXdPiwTy_Kb_K0/edit 
(click checkbox to reset and again to recalculate the random number).

Comment: can't click the box.  Sheet is View Only

Comment: Ok I made it editable

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). You may also try the [Blank sheet maker here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383).

Comment: Would you be open to using Excel?

Comment: @GabrielPierce Well would be interesting to see how to do it on Excel but ultimately final solution will be for Google Sheets.

Comment: LET would be my recommendation. Its the one formula that Excel has that GS does not. and its a cool one

Comment: @Gabriel Pierce Yes I've seen sometimes it being mentioned as an alternative. For sure I will soon take a look as probably some stuff I work on will need to be done on Excel I'm just postponing it as much as I can because I really like Google Sheets and Query function. But ```LET``` seems very versitile indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `RANDBETWEEN` within a `MIN` - `MAX`

```
=MAX(
  MIN(
   RANDBETWEEN(((((D3*100)+(B3*100))/2)-100),((((D3*100)+(B3*100))/2)+100))/100,
   9
  ),
 0
)*A1
```

Comment: Does not exactly answer the question of how to return first argument of condition without recalculation. But it does fix my problem and I will use this. Thanks!

Comment: You're talking about declaring a variable and conditionally return it. With the extra cell you actually did that. With a regular formula it's not possible. With a custom function written, you can.

Comment: I See. Thank you. I will soon need to rewrite this as a custom function as I need to find a way to make probability of 70% for the final value to fall between (X+Y)/2+RANDOM(-1,+1) and the rest 30% to fall between ... RANDOM(-2,+2). I assume this is only possible with custom function not regular formulas.